# Using <T> on IPagination

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, asp.net-mvc-3, mvccontrib

I have the following class

```
  public class NavigationIEntity
    {
        public int CurrentId { get; set; }
        public string View { get; set; }
        public string Controller { get; set; }
        public IPagination<IEntity> Entities  { get; set; } 
    }
```

I have the following helper to instantiate

```
public static NavigationIEntity Create<T>(int currentId, string view, string controller, IPagination<T> entities) where T : IEntity
 {
      return new NavigationIEntity { 
      Entities = entities, View = view, Controller = controller, CurrentId = currentId
      };
}
```

However i get the following error.

[image]

EDIT: I've tried the following, "IPagination entities" ie not T

```
public static NavigationIEntity Create(int currentId, string view, string controller, IPagination<IEntity> entities)
{
                return new NavigationIEntity { Entities = entities, View = view, Controller = controller, CurrentId = currentId };
}
```

but don't know how best resolve

[image]

DistributionUnit implements IEntity

Comment: Curious but if T is constrained to `IEntity` why not just use `IEntity` instead of T?

Comment: I'm assuming DistributionUnit implements IEntity, correct? (Might be a silly question, but it never hurts to double check).

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a generic type into a non generic "slot". (Entities is explicitly IEntity)

Generics `where` is a compiler check, just checks that you're using the object right.

It does not guarantee that the object is of that type at run time.

In your case, because it's explicit anyway, you can do:

```
public static NavigationIEntity Create<T>(int currentId, string view, string controller, IPagination<IEntity> entities)
```

It will work for anything that inherits from `IEntity` anyway.

OR, you can do a little cheat, that will keep the signature the same, but will do what you want:

```
   public static NavigationIEntity Create<T>(int currentId, string view, string controller, IPagination<T> entities) where T : IEntity
    {
        return new NavigationIEntity
        {
            Entities = entities as IPagination<IEntity>,
            View = view,
            Controller = controller,
            CurrentId = currentId
        };
    }
```

Comment: right. i follow. Thanks for the above code. I've tried this and it seems the cast "nulls" Entities. ie when i debug there are records in the IPagination in the method signature.